# Track Excel Sheet Changes

Tags: excel, excel-2003, vba

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please.

I'm using the code below to track changes to a Excel worksheet, automatically inserting a date into column 'A' and the word 'No' into column 'AE' when the value of any cell within the range B5:Q2000 is changed.

```
Option Explicit
    Public preValue As Variant
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim Cell As Range, res As Variant
      If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
       On Error Resume Next
       If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B5:Q2000")) Is Nothing Then
       If Target.Value <> preValue And Target.Value <> "" Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Range("A5:A" & Target.Row).Value = Date
            Range("AE5:AE" & Target.Row).Value = "No"
            Application.EnableEvents = True
            Target.ClearComments
          '  Target.AddComment.Text Text:="Previous Value was " & preValue & Chr(10) & "Revised " & Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy") & Chr(10) & "By " & Environ("UserName")
            Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 35
        End If
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Count = 1 Then preValue = Target.Value
End Sub
```

Unfortunately I've come across a problem which I'm not sure how to resolve.

If the user inserts data into cells D5 and D10, the date and the word 'No' are added to the correct columns (A and AE) for these two rows.

However, unfortunately, the 'No' value and the date are also added to the these columns for the rows in between i.e D6-D9, even though the user hasn't entered any other data on these rows, and I'm not sure where the problem lies.

I just wondered whether someone may be able to take a look at this and offer some guidance on how I may go about solving this.

Many thanks and kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code is applying the changes starting with `A5` and `AE5` through `Target's` row.  To have the code change only the rows of the selected cell, change this:

```
Range("A5:A" & Target.Row).Value = Date
Range("AE5:AE" & Target.Row).Value = "No"
```

to this:

```
Range("A" & Target.Row).Value = Date
Range("AE" & Target.Row).Value = "No"
```

Also, you don't seem to be using the variable `Cell` or `res`.  You might want to delete that line of code.

Comment: Hi @Doug Glancy, thank you for taking the time to reply to my post and for the solution. It works great!

Kind regards